# Multiple Plots on the same page in R

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot my two figures on the same page in R.
Two plots are: Scatter and bat plot
Used: par(mfrow=c(2,1)) 
      p 
      s
where p is the bar plot and s is the scatter plot.
When I used the command: first p plot shows and at the end only s-- scatter plot is shown.
I know both the plots are there but could not fix it!!
I really need a help here.

Comment: please share your code what have done till now. i cannot see any plot code in your question.

Comment: i think you are looking for `par(mfrow=c(1,2))`. Meaning `1` row and `2` columns.

Comment: dataset <- read_excel(file.choose())
View(dataset)
Dataset:
Category Jan  Feb
Food 25 100
Makeup 10 150
Travel 200 120
Drinks 164 36

I was printing the plots in two rows and one coloumn
Code:
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
p<-ggplot(dataset, aes(x=Category, y=Jan)) +geom_bar(stat="identity",)
s<-ggplot(data, aes(x=Category, y=Feb))+geom_point()

Comment: Please execute `dput(dataset)` and share output.

Comment: It's just showing me a blank output.

Comment: The `ggplot` function for `s` is using wrong `dataframe`. Change it to `dataset` and drawing problem will be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

There is small problem in code provided by `OP`. The wrong `dataframe` is used in scatter plot.

The correct implementation could be:

```
#The dataset read is has been modified to read from text as provided in OP
dataset <- read.table(text = "Category  Jan Feb 
Food    25  100 
Makeup  10 150 
Travel  200 120 
Drinks  164 36", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 

# mfrow setting will not have any effect on ggplot2 based 
par(mfrow=c(2,1)) 

p<-ggplot(dataset, aes(x=Category, y=Jan)) + geom_bar(stat="identity",)
# OP has used just data for ggplot function to s
s<-ggplot(dataset, aes(x=Category, y=Feb)) + geom_point() 

p
s

But the graphs will be drawn in separate pages.
```

`grid.arrange()` function `gridExtra` can be used to draw multiple `ggplot` based plots in same screen.

Comment: I realized used of the different dataset.It's just my typo. I have two different plots in variable p and s, now I want them in the same frame or page.I tried grid.Extra by installing, but it shows me an error, saying function not found.

Comment: @Bandana Yes. I can see the error with latest package. There are other options. One of them could be using `cowplot` package. I'm not sure when `grid.Extra` will be fixed.

Comment: @Bandana Is your `r` version is version 3.4.3? Perhaps that's root-cause.

Comment: Thank you. I used gridExtra changing the version.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multi-graph function and plot any number of graphs on the same page. 
Examples below:
http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_(ggplot2)/

Note: it's a custom function, so it's not in any packages. You should just copy and paste, then run it in your console.